# Matlab: How to plot coordinate locations using x markers in a contour map?

Tags: matlab, plot, contour, marker

I need to plot the locations of 3 treasures on a contour map.The coordinates are in a matrix (3x2) called "treasures", the first column contains the y coordinates, and the second column the x coordinates.

Using an X marker I was asked to plot the treasures locations using a marker size of 15, a line width of 4 and a red color.

How could I do that? [the image should look like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VlJPA.png)

Comment: First read [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and provide a [minimal valuable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). The people are willing to help but show them that you appreciate it by making a bit more effort when asking

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you need to read a basic tutorial on matlab first before you take on this project.

plotting scattered points can be done in matlab using the command `plot`. Assuming your treasure locations is x and y (both can be a vector for multiple points), you can plot those using

```
plot(x,y,'rx','markersize',15)
```

Comment: Yes, I just started a MATLAB course so I'm still learning the basics. Thank you for the help.